# How to override template/view of SilverStripe's User Defined Form

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am developing a simple SilverStripe project for learning purpose. I am using [SilverStripe User Defined Form module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms) to create form pages.

The way the user defined form module renders the form in the template/ view is using the $UserDefinedForm variable in the content field. Now, I need to do some customization to the built-in User Defined Form template. So I decided to override the controller and page.

This is my EventPage

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm;

    class EventPage extends UserDefinedForm
    {

    }
}
```

This is my EventPageController

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\UserForms\Control\UserDefinedFormController;

    class EventPageController extends UserDefinedFormController
    {
        
    }
}
```

This is my EventPage.ss

```
<h1>Event Page</h1>

$UserDefinedForm
```

This page is overridden, but the form is not rendered. How can I render the form?

Comment: Have you tried to use just $Form

Comment: I tried. does not work

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer might help. 
ContactPage.php

namespace InsiteApps\CMS\Model {

```
use SilverStripe\UserForms\Control\UserDefinedFormController;
use SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm;

class ContactPage extends UserDefinedForm
{
    private static $table_name = 'ContactPage';

}


class ContactPageController extends UserDefinedFormController
{

}
```

}

In your theme, templates folder (the folder structure is dependant on your namespace)

templates/InsiteApps/CMS/Model/Layout/ContactPage.ss

`<div class="contact-page-form">
    $Form
</div>`